# Which NPC can be pickpocketed with a 100% success rate above level 100?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

In the OSRS Trailblazer League the "Skilling Prodigy" Relic allows you to get a permanent skill boost of +12 to all your non-combat skills.
Now in the base game Knights of Ardougne are a very popular thieving training method since at level 95 it is no longer possible to fail pickpockets when the Ardougne Medium diary is completed.

If I understand the current league mechanic correctly, theoretically it would be possible to boost thieving up to level 116 (+12 from the relic and +5 from a Stew).

So what is there a higher level NPC from which it's possible to steal? (At level 116 with both the Ardougne Diary and the Thieving cape if necessary.)

Comment: FWIW: you can also boost your thieving drinking Sq'irk juice you make from the fruits obtained in the Sorceress' Garden. It gives you +3 if I recall correctly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You slightly misunderstood the boosting mechanic. You get a permanent +12 boost, but that means other boosts with maximums under +12 don't work. Stews have a max boost of +5 regardless of the skilling prodigy relic. Therefore, the maximum thieving level is 111/99. There is also some reason to suspect that boosts past 99 have no effect on pickpocket success chance. I recall a jmod looking into something similar for mining granite with a dragon pickaxe boost. The jmod decided that boosts past 99 have no effect on mining speed.

The next NPC after Ardougne knights in order of thieving level required are Yanille watchmen at level 65. With 111/99 thieving, the completed Ardougne diary and a thieving cape it is still possible to fail to pickpocket a watchman.

Comment: I be skeptical about boosts past 99 for "skilling" skills not making a difference, like in your dragon pickaxe example, but without evidence denoting so, we can't say for sure.  For [Watchmen](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Watchman) the wiki page has a graph for the pickpocket success chance.  It appears to go up by about 0.78% per level.  I can't tell for sure with the graph, but with the thieving cape and diary, you have about a 76% chance at level 99.  If the boosts works, at level 111 you'd have about a 85.36% chance to not fail, thus it's likely Ardougne Knights are the best still.

Comment: Skilling stat boosting past 99 is almost always irrelevant (source: Mod Ash on Twitter https://archive.is/F3agE) @TimmyJim